# iOS, appstore app published

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My App got approved on the appstore,

but on itunes connect, when i go /more/view on appstore

the app opens on the US territory, Im in Aus,

the app is set to work on all territories, but I cannot find it using search on the appstore,

so how long does it take to be available on Aus market? .)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about the App store not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to 2 days is the rollout time. Just have patience.

I'm in Latin America and sometimes I wait several hours to rollout, but in Europe up to 1 day and in Australia up to 2 days.